# Must a neighbourhood of a cut point $x$ of a topological space $X$ contain points from all path-components of $X\setminus\{x\}$?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

Must a neighbourhood $N$ of a [cut point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-point) $x$ of a (path-connected) topological space $X$  contain points from all path-components of $X\setminus\{x\}$?

---

The answer appears to be, clearly, yes.  However, I can't think of an argument to justify this other than simply state that it follows immediately from the definition of a cut point. Is this the case, however?  Or there's an obvious proof/counterexample I'm missing?

Comment: Can you please add some details to your question?  What, precisely, is your definition of a cut point?  What kinds of topological spaces are you considering (must they be path-connected)?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yes, path-connected.  Here the definition I'm using: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-point

Comment: Please edit your question to include this context.

Comment: @XanderHenderson It was done before your comment....

Comment: @XanderHenderson Could you remove the closing request on the thread?  It's not justified.

Comment: I'm sorry; I was perhaps not clear about what I meant.  Questions on MSE should be self-contained.  A link to an outside source is helpful, but a proper definition of a cut point is a relatively vital part of your question.  The definition (or, at least, a precis) should be included in the question. :)

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be. Imagine a [topologist's circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696533/quasi-circle-is-not-contractible) that has another segment with the wavy line thing converging to one (nice) side of the 'circle'. Then the same segment goes to the other side to do the same wavy thing and converge to yet another copy of the topologist's circle. A point in the segment with the two wavy things is a cut point. But there are 4 path connected components in this space.

Comment: @conditionalMethod I didn't notice this comment of yours before posting my answer below. I haven't fully understood your counterexample, but perhaps the `metric-spaces` tag is what created the contradiction with my proof?

Comment: @WhatsUp  Hum, I'm not sure.  Perhaps I should remove the metric space tag - it's more of a topological question anyways.

Comment: @WhatsUp Done! Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: The close votes to this post is really disappointing. I do not see anything missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this example. But note that this example is not $T_1$!
It might not be fair to be talking about a cut point if the space is not $T_1$.

When $X$ is $T_1$ then the proof in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3453915/713897) shows that the statement is true.

---

Take the space $X=\{2,3,4\}$ with the topology $T=\{\emptyset, \{3\}, \{2,3\}, \{3,4\}, X\}$.

With this topology $X$ is connected, since all non-empty open sets meet at $3$.
The point $x=3$ is a cut point, since $Y=X\setminus \{3\}=\{2,4\}$ is disconnected by the (relative to $Y$) open sets $\{2,3\}\cap Y$ and $\{3,4\}\cap Y$.

---

We can connect $2$ to $3$ by the path $p(t)=2$ for $t\in [0,1/2]$ and $p(t)=3$ for $t\in(1/2,1]$. This is continuous since $p^{-1}(\{3\})=(1/2,1]$ is open and $p^{-1}(\{2,3\})=[0,1]$ is also open.

We can connect $3$ and $4$ by $p(t)=4$ for $t\in[0,1/2]$ and $p(t)=3$ for $t\in(1/2,1]$. As above, $p(\{3\})=(1/2,1]$ is open and $p(\{3,4\})=[0,1]$ is also open.

We can connect $2$ to $4$ by $p(t)=2$ for $t\in[0,1/3]$, $p(t)=3$ for $t\in(1/3,2/3)$, and $p(t)=4$ for $t\in(2/3,1]$. This is continuous since $p^{-1}(\{2,3\})=[0,2/3)$ is open, $p^{-1}(\{3\})=(1/2,2/3)$ is open and $p^{-1}(\{3,4\})=(2/3,4]$ is also open.

So, $X$ is path connected.

---

Now, the neighborhood $\{3\}$ of $3$ doesn't intersect $Y=X\setminus\{3\}$, let alone its path components.

Comment: Right. That's why I was worrying about the condition $\{x\}$ being closed. P.S. after connecting $2, 3$ and $3, 4$, you don't need to connect $2,4$ manually, since path connectedness is an equivalence relation.

Comment: Thanks. This is a very revealing example.  It shows how one goes about creating paths and proving their continuity in rather contrived situations.

Comment: @WhatsUp At least in Wikipedia the definition of cut point does include the assumption that the space is $T_1$.

Comment: @WhatsUp But then in the same page, the first property in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-point#Topological_properties_of_cut-point_spaces) doesn't assume it. Anyway, the exact form of a definition is not very important but to understand how the different properties interact when one has them or don't have them.

Comment: I see... I didn't read that page very carefully and didn't even see the $T_1$ assumption. Now we all understand these subtleties here.

Comment: What made you consider a counterexample and not a proof?  Intuition or some other hint?

Comment: @Stephen Well, the fact that one can get the non-intersection part very cheaply if the cut point is open makes you try to see if all other properties can also be obtained. Similar to when $X$ was only connected, the fact that path-connected components can be different from connected components makes you think that in that case something can be done to make it not work.

Answer (score 4):

Assume that $X$ is path-connected and $T_1$ and that $X \backslash \{x\}$ is not path-connected.

Let $U$ be a path component of $X \backslash \{x\}$ and let $u\in U$ be any point. Then there exists a point $v \in X\backslash\{x\}$ which is not in $U$.

Since $X$ is path-connected, there is a path (i.e. continuous map) $p:[0, 1] \rightarrow X$ such that $p(0) = u$ and $p(1) = v$.

But the path $p$ must pass the cut point $x$ - otherwise it would be a path in $X \backslash \{x\}$.

Therefore the inverse image $p^{-1}(x)$ is a non-empty closed subset of $(0, 1)$ (here we use the assumption that $X$ is $T_1$).

Let $t$ be the minimum element of $p^{-1}(x)$ (which exists by compactness). Since $N$ is a neighborhood of $x$ and $p$ is continuous, the inverse image $p^{-1}(N)$ contains an open subset of $(0, 1)$ containing $t$.

This means that there exists $0 < s < t$ such that $p(s)$ is in $N$. It only remains to show that $p(s)$ is in $U$.

Consider the sub-path $p\vert_{[0, s]}$. It connects the two points $u$ and $p(s)$. Moreover, this sub-path does not pass the point $x$, by minimality of $t$. Therefore $p(s)$ lies in the same path connected component as $u$, which is $U$.

Comment: The problem in your argument (at least the first) is in the third paragraph. Connectedness of $X$ doesn't imply existence of a path.

Comment: @conditionalMethod I somehow assumed that $X$ is path-connected, and it was added to the question. However the removal of the `metric-spaces` tag might invalidate my argument that $\{x\}$ is a closed set.

Comment: Path connectedness of X is implied, yes.

Comment: Well, if they change the hypotheses the question changes.

Comment: @Stephen You mean, given, right?

Comment: Yes, given/assumed.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Is the argument in your comment only valid if we don't assume path-connectedness?

Comment: @Stephen Yes, my example was a space (not path connected) that has cut point (in particular it is connected), but some neighborhood of the cut point doesn't intersect all path-connected components.

Comment: @conditionalMethod I see. sorry for any confusion.  I did update the question 9 minutes after asking it, however.  So normally it should have appeared before your comment.

Comment: So, to recap - the answer is yes - $N$ contains points from all path connected components.  I'm still going through your proof. (And thanks for providing it.)

Comment: @Stephen Now there is proof for the path connected case, and counterexample for when that condition is dropped. Nothing lost.

Comment: Well... at least if $X$ is a metric space (or weaker, if $\{x\}$ is closed in $X$). I don't know whether there needs a fix otherwise.

Comment: I understand your proof.  I didn't think it would involve so much work to prove this, but I also don't see a simplification! I'm trying to find a way to generalise it.